# Jquery steps deletes form content when initialized

Tags: jquery, meteor

i'm using Jquery steps with Meteor Autoform it works well with the insetion form , 
but when initializing my wizard , my pre filled fields become empty , i actualiy can see my fields filled then they become empty when the wizard in initialized .

```
Template.editEmployee.rendered=function(){


// Initialize steps plugin
var form = $("#employeeEditForm");
form.validate({
    errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },
    rules: {
        confirm: {
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    }
});
form.children("div").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    enableContentCache: true,
    preloadContent: true,
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
    {
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

}

here is my template :

```
<template name="editEmployee">
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12">
              {{#autoForm collection='Meteor.users' doc=employee type='update' id='employeeEditForm'}}
                  <div>
                      <h3>Profile</h3>
                      <section>
                        {{> afQuickField name='profile'}}
                      </section>
                      <h3>Settings</h3>
                      <section>


                        {{> afQuickField name='userSettings'}}
                      </section>
                  </div>

              {{/autoForm}}

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</template>
```

Comment: Any solution to this? I am running into the same problem.